# I can't get the text written in the <textarea> using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I tried everything from

```
var data = $('#editme').val();
var data = $('#editme').value(); 
var data = $('#editme').html;
var data = $('#editme').val;
```

nothing is working.

This is my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {                  
            $("#p1").click(function(e) {    
                e.preventDefault();
                console.log('select_link clicked');
                var data = $('#editme').val();
                console.log(data);
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: JSON.stringify(data),
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    url: 'http://localhost:3000/Upload/newQuestion',                        
                    success: function(data) {
                        console.log('success');
                        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

and also this is the text area:

```
<textarea id="editme" name= "editme" class="form-control" rows="4" cols="50" placeholder="Post question."spellcheck="true" ></textarea>
```

Comment: are you using same id on page for other element ?

Comment: works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/pevans02/2M4C5/ and why are you stringifying a string?

Comment: @SubodhGhulaxe i think in that case of duplicates id, it will take the first id

Comment: may be he is using first id for anchor tag.

Comment: There is no need to try random properties, read the [**documentation**](https://api.jquery.com/val/): *"The `.val()` method is primarily used to get the values of form elements such as `input`, `select` and `textarea`."*

Comment: no duplicate ids on the page. I'm sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code is working for me check working **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/pUUYE/)**

```
$('#editme').val();
```

will work

1. Check you included [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)
2. Check you are not using same id (#pa or #editme) again on same page